# Clone constructors when overriding a C++ class?

Tags: c++, class

Let's have class A with hell of a lot of constructors. I want to make class B derived from A in a very minimalistic way, say just add a few members, and keep all the constructors. Is there a way to do that without implementing all the constructors and just calling the same ones from A?

Comment: Yes there is. You can inherit the base class's constructors. See the linked question and your C++ textbook for more information.